# Pass Javascript Variable to HTML Code inside append()

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-ui

I Would like to pass a variable to the html code I want to append:

```
var max = 1;    
$(wraper).on("click", ".add_field_button", function(e){ //on add input click
   e.preventDefault();
   if(max < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
     max++;
     console.log(max); // max now is equal to 2
     $(wrapper).append('<input id="street" name="street[{{$max}}]" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="" value="">');
     }
})
```

Instead of using $max inside the html code of the input I would like to use the value of the max js variable, so that I can get street[2]

I've seen many solutions on how to pass only the variable to the append(), but not the variable inside a HTML code...

Comment: Instead of {{$max}} use ${max}

Comment: Shouldn't template literals use backticks, not apostrophes?

Comment: @MasoodAslami Didn't work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(wrapper).append('<input id="street" name="street[' + max + ']" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="" value="">');
```

Or

```
$(wrapper).append(concat('<input id="street" name="street[', max, ']" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="" value="">'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
var max = 1;    
$(wraper).on("click", ".add_field_button", function(e){ //on add input click
   e.preventDefault();
   if(max < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
     max++;
     console.log(max); // max now is equal to 2
    var $el = $("#street");
    $el.attr("name", 'street' + max);
     }
})
```